# Convert strings to list

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

I'm stumped on this:

I have a list that supposedly contains other lists but right now they are being read as str in python like this:

YACKETY = ["['11111', '3000', 'USD', '0']", "['11112', '3000', 'USD', '0']", "['11113', '3000', 'USD', '0']", "['11114', '3000', 'USD', '0']"]

But each of the elements in YACKETY are supposed to be lists as well, right now they are strings. I want to make each of these elements in YACKETY become mutable lists again. How can I approach this?

Tuples are immutable, so that is out of the solution since I want the elements in those lists in YACKETY to be mutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `ast.literal_eval` for safe conversion from string to lists.

```
>>> import ast
>>> YACKETY = ["['11111', '3000', 'USD', '0']", "['11112', '3000', 'USD', '0']", "['11113', '3000', 'USD', '0']", "['11114', '3000', 'USD', '0']"]
>>> converted = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in YACKETY]
>>> converted
[['11111', '3000', 'USD', '0'], ['11112', '3000', 'USD', '0'], ['11113', '3000', 'USD', '0'], ['11114', '3000', 'USD', '0']]
```

Comment: Or `map(ast.literal_eval, YACKETY)`

Comment: @Haidro List comprehension seems more preferable over map and filter. http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the correct approach is to figure out where these lists are turning into strings and stop that from happening. Each element in YACKETY is a list that was passed to str(). Since you don't want them as strings, you probably want to figure out why these lists are getting passed to str() and fix that.

If you can't control that, there's always the big red button:

```
yacklist = [eval(item) for item in YACKETY]
```

Comment: `eval` is not recommended.